# Migrate assertXY Statements from JUnit4 to Junit5 in a fast way?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, junit5

We have thousands of unit tests build with JUnit4 in our project. At the moment, we are in the progress of migrating to JUnit5.

However, the different method signatures for `assertXY` statements, which were changed from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5, require a lot of manual efforts and/or time if we migrate them in a manual way.

**Question:**

- Is there a fast way of achieving this migration (JUnit 4 -> JUnit 5), eg. a transformer tool or a `sed` command to swap the arguments for the `assertXY` statements?

**Example in JUnit4**

```
@Test
public void testCreatePersonCorrect() {
    String name = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String title = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    Person person = service.createPerson(title, name);
    assertNotNull("could not create a person", person);
    assertEquals("title did not equal for that person", title, person.getTitle());
    assertEquals("name did not equal for that person", name, person.getName());
 }
```

**Example in JUnit5**

```
@Test
public void testCreatePersonCorrect() {
    String name = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String title = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    Person person = service.createPerson(title, name);
    assertNotNull(person, "could not create a person");
    assertEquals(title, person.getTitle(), "title did not equal for that person");
    assertEquals(name, person.getName(), "name did not equal for that person");
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find JUnit Pioneer's [convert-junit4-to-junit5](https://github.com/junit-pioneer/convert-junit4-to-junit5) tool useful.

If you're using IntelliJ IDEA, it has built-in support for migrating from JUnit 4 to JUnit Jupiter. See Trisha Gee's [IntelliJ IDEA. Migrating from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8UTTTDtbH0) video on YouTube for examples.

Otherwise, the refactoring trick suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65936638/388980 can be a viable alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This worked like a charm. I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea before you start the source processing...

I would create a custom wrapper class for the JUnit4 asserts (org.junit.Assert) like this:

```
public static class YourAsserts {
    ...
    public static void assertNotNull(String string, Object object) {
        Assert.assertNotNull(string, object);
    }
    ...
}
```

After then I would remove the JUnit4 and JUnit5 from the dependencies and organise the imports to use your custom assert stuff. Add the JUnit4 back and test the changes. All test should still be passed.

Select the methods in your wrapper and change the signature of the methods using the refactoring tools. (in Eclipse: Alt + Shift + C)
If changed all methods, simple remove your wrapper class and add the JUnit5 to the dependencies and organise imports again. Run the tests again.

This worked for me, but currently I'm using Hamcrest. That's more powerful.

Comment: Yup. Also thought about wrapping it, but was wondering If there is another solution.